# How do I launch a URL in Firefox in the background from Ubuntu command line?

Tags: firefox, unix, command-line, ubuntu

I use this command from the Terminal to launch a URL in Firefox:

```
firefox reader.google.com &
```

I put the ampersand at the end so that it won't put my Terminal window in the background, but Gnome just ignores this and opens a new Firefox browser window on top of the Terminal. Is there a way to launch Firefox behind the Terminal? What I want to do is continue working on the command line while the page loads, which sometimes can take a few seconds.

Comment: i think this belongs on superuser

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In firefox's `about:config` page set preference:

```
'browser.tabs.loadDivertedInBackground' to 'true'.
```

Comment: But this unfortunately has some undesirable side effects... e.g. the page is opened in a background tab, which I would prefer to be selected.

Comment: You can muck with your window manager's "Focus Stealing Prevention" to get something closer to what you want, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

```
firefox "http://www.google.com/" &
```

This works for me just fine.  Try using quotes and a full URL.

Comment: This works so long as tabs are off. Which I might do because the above method has side effects

Answer (score -2):

firefox & -Will just open in background and you can surf. 
firefox --search "your text" & could directly give you the search results 
for to open in separate tab or windows just try --new tab or -- new windows followed by your url. you can find it just give firefox --help in terminal