# open URL in background tab via command line?

Tags: firefox, command-line, background, windows-shell

Is there any way to open a background tab via the command line?

for example (in Windows): 
C:\Progra~1\Mozilla\Firefox\firefox.exe -new-tab http://www.yahoo.com

will always open that tab and make that the focused tab. I can't seem to find a way to open that tab in the background. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276650/how-do-i-launch-a-url-in-firefox-in-the-background-from-ubuntu-command-line